# What is the primitive function of $xe^{x^2+2x}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I need to know the primitive function (Antiderivative) of this function:
f(x)= $xe^{x^2+2x}$ without using integral please. Also, please how could I find the primitive functions of those kind like v(x)u(x) ? is there any technique concerning those types? Thanks in advance

Comment: Rewrite as $(x+1)e^{x^2+2x}-e^{x^2+2x}$. The first has an easy antiderivative. The antiderivative of the second cannot be written as a closed form expression using elementary functions.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner What error? let me explain to you, the function in the exercise was $\left(x+1\right)e^{x^2+2x}$ so it's equals to : $xe^{x^2+2x}+e^{x^2+2x}$ the second one, I mean $e^{x^2+2x}$ is easy to find and it's primitive is : $\frac{1}{2x+2}e^{x^2+2x}$ but the other, I failed to find it.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I didn't get it, why should I rewrite it like that?

Comment: @AmineMarzouki It was written that way to exploit the fact that one of the primitives of $u'(x)e^{u(x)}$ is $e^{u(x)}$.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Ooops I did a mistake, it's wrong, sorry

Comment: @AmineMarzouki No. The derivative of $\frac 1{2x+2} \exp(x^2 + 2x)$ is $-\frac 2{(2x+2)^2}\exp(x^2 + 2x) + \exp(x^2 + 2x)$.

Comment: @martini Yes you're right, my mistake

Comment: @AmineMarzouki He was talking about the [error function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erf.html), which is defined by: $$\operatorname{erf}(x):=\dfrac2{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^x e^{-t^2}\mathrm dt.$$

Comment: @Workaholic yes, Thanks mate.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Good idea, thank you !

Comment: @Workaholic We are not allowed to use integral in this exercise :) but thanks once again for letting me know

Answer (score 2):

From your comments, it seems that the original requested primitive was that of the function $f\colon x\mapsto(x+1)e^{x^2+2x}$. Decomposing it into $x e^{x^2+2x}$ and $e^{x^2+2x}$ wont yield a satisfying result, since the former will involve the [error function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erf.html). Instead, exploit the fact that the primitive of $u'(x)e^{u(x)}$ is $e^{u(x)}$. Here we can clearly see that $f(x)$ can be written as $\tfrac12(2x+2)e^{x^2+2x}$ which is $\tfrac{1}{2}(x^2+2x)'e^{x^2+2x}$. Can you now conclude what the primitive of $f$ is?